# browser supportability

Tags: css

I have a css gradient button it works fine for Firefox and Google Chrome but it is not working in ie6. The following code i used.

code:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7db72f), to(#4e7d0e));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7db72f,  #4e7d0e);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#7db72f', endColorstr='#4e7d0e');
```

please help to me

Comment: I wanted to note you few things. First, you're not including prefixes for Microsoft Internet Explorer 10+ and Opera. Second, your WebKit syntax is old, very old. Third, you're not including official version without prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85%29.aspx) help?

> The object that the filter is applied to must have layout before the filter effect will display. You can give the object layout by setting the height or width property, setting the position property to absolute, setting the writingMode property to tb-rl, or setting the contentEditable property to true.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is a problem of spacing between `progid : DXImageTransform.Microsoft`. write like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7db72f', endColorstr='7db72f');
```

read this article http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient